# Trouble using variables in VBA SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update a table using variables in VBA for Access. The statement is below.

```
DB.Execute "UPDATE tblSearchersList SET '" & vSearcherDay & "' = " & VHours & " 
WHERE Member= '" & Me.cboMember.Column(1) & "'AND [Mission] = '" & Me.Mission & "'"
```

tblSearcherList is table to update

vSearcherDay is a variable that combines the letter "d" with a number, et(1,2,3,4,5) depending on other query

VHours is a decimal number (number of hours)

Member is a text value from Form Field Me.cboMember.Column(1)

Mission is a text value from form field Me.Mission

I get Runtime `error 3061 - Too few parameters expected 2.`

Hope I can get some help with this as I have been fighting it for awhile and am losing the battle.

Thanks

New code is this:

Sorry bout the comments thing. I am new and didn't quite know how to do this.

```
DB.Execute "UPDATE tblSearchersList SET " & vSearcherDay &_
" = " & VHours & " WHERE Member= '" & Me.cboMember.Column(1) & "' &_
" And [Mission] = '" & Me.Mission & "'"
```

I am quite embarrassed about this but I had the Member field name wrong. Should've been
MemberName instead. I really do appreciate all the quick help I got and will do better next time. It works perfectly. Thank you all.

Comment: Do you have a space between the value being inserted for VHours and the WHERE clause? The formatting seems to show that you're running straight on in the text, which could be the issue.

Comment: When you build the `UPDATE` statement, store it in a string variable such as *strUpdate*.  Then `Debug.Print strUpdate` before you `DB.Execute strUpdate`.  You can examine the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window.  Copy the statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.  If you need more help, add that statement to your question and tell us the error message it triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use apostrophes around field name. Instead

```
SET '" & vSearcherDay & "' = " &
```

do

```
SET " & vSearcherDay & " = " &
```

Comment: Now I get Runtime error 3061 - Too few parameters expected 1 instead of 2. Looks like I'm getting closer. Here is the code now:

DB.Execute "UPDATE tblSearchersList SET " & vSearcherDay & " = " & VHours & " WHERE Member= '" & Me.cboMember.Column(1) & "'AND [Mission] = '" & Me.Mission & "'"

Comment: Can you update your question with new code instead of putting it into comments? Also in `'AND [Mission]` try to add space before AND `' AND [Mission]`